# JPA - analog of LobCreator from hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

in pure Hibernate i can do:

```
Blob blob= Hibernate.getLobCreator(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).createBlob(inputStream, len);
```

How to do this in jpa (with hibernate as  provider)?

In pure hibernate i made user type for blobs, which used `setBinaryStream` prepared statement. This solution worked for me perfectly and i'm looking for a way to port it to JPA.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `@Lob` annotation on your persistent property ([Annotation Lob](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Lob)):

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

private byte[] content;
...

@Lob
public byte[] getContent() {
return content;
}

public void setContent(byte[] newContent) {
this.content = newContent;
}
}
```

In your code you can transform a stream in a byte[] with a code like this:

```
@Transient
public void setContentFromInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException 
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int l = 0;
    do {
        l = is.read(buff);
        if (l > 0)
        {
            baos.write(buff, 0, l);
        }
    } while (l > 0);
    
    is.close();
    baos.flush();
    baos.close();
    
    content = baos.toByteArray();
}
```

The `@Lob` annotation can also be used with String, in this case you'll obtain a CLOB on the DB

You must pay attention to the size of the `byte[]` to avoid `OutOfMemoryError`.

To use only streams you must rely on the specific jdbc vendor implementation.
For example if you are using Hibernate >= 3.6 you can change they type of MyEntity.content to Blob and write:

```
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
Session session = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate(); 
Blob newContent = session.getLobHelper().createBlob(inputStream, len); 
entity.setContent(newContent);
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks fro answer! But what do you mean by `To use only streams you must rely on the specific jdbc vendor implementation.`? In pure hibernate i made user type for blobs, which used `setBinaryStream` prepared statement. This solution worked for me perfectly and i'm looking for a way to port it to JPA.

Comment: The code I provided is pure JPA, but with JPA you cannot map an InputStream to a DB column, this code will not work: @Lob InputStream getContent(). To use InputStream without loading the byte[] in memory you must rely on the JPA implementation you are using (Hibernate in your case). There is no way using only JPA 2.0 API to work with BLOB using InputStream like you can do with Hibernate API

Comment: Please, bear with me. How do i rely on hibernate to do this?

Comment: If you are using Hibernate >= 3.6 you can write: `Session session = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate(); LobHelper helper = session.getLobHelper(); Blob content = helper.createBlob(inputStream, len); `. Then you can set the type of the property MyEntity.content to Blob and set it with your blob. I'm editing my post to include this solution

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to save any serialized object into a column, set the column type in the database as blob, use the SerializationHelper class provided by Hibernate, and put this code in yout bean class.

```
class MyBean{

    @Column
    private byte[] object;

    @Transient
    public Object getObjectDeserialized() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        if(this.object == null)
            return new String(); // or another type
        return SerializationHelper.deserialize(this.object);
    }

    byte[] getObject() {
        return this.object;
    }

    void setObject(byte[] object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    @Transient
    public void setObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
        if(obj != null)
            this.object = SerializationHelper.serialize((Serializable) obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really "provided" by Hibernate, it's an internal implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

the xxxx maybe you can transfer what you want to do .

class XXXBean{

```
@Column
private byte[] object;

@Transient
public Object getObjectDeserialized() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    if(this.object == null)
        return new String(); // or another type
    return SerializationHelper.deserialize(this.object);
}

byte[] getObject() {
    return this.object;
}

void setObject(byte[] object) {
    this.object = object;
}

@Transient
public void setObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
    if(obj != null)
        this.object = SerializationHelper.serialize((Serializable) obj);
}
```

}